# Spyder and Matplotlib. I obtain several plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I am working in Spyder (Python) to analyze some information. I am plotting the data, but something odd is happening. When I run the code all together, the final plot is ok. Doing the same in the Spyder Console I get several figures, one by one.

Is it possible to run command by command in the console and to obtain a proper graph?

I include the code I am working with, but it is not the important part. As said above, running it all together, runs properly.

Thanks,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(start=0,
              stop=np.pi*2,
              step=np.pi*2/12)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, "bo", label='First Line')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='Second Line')

plt.xlabel('Angle, rads')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('This is an Example')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Image running all the code:

[image: Running all]

Image running a single command:

[image: Runnung a command]

Image running another command:

[image]

Comment: Does `plt.show` in the console show the combined plot?

Comment: Hello Jared- No. It does not.

Comment: Have you tried using `plt.ioff()` to disable interactive mode? And finally, using `plt.show()` to plot all. [Reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ioff.html)